# Laravel 5 API NGINX without serve?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I want to use my Laravel API as (example) apiname.laravelsite.com/v1/api, without `php artisan serve`. Currently only serving from a port and then visiting that port through apiname.laravelsite.com:8125/v1/api works.

Does anybody have experience with this? I already tried setting up my NGINX server (with php 7.0, php-fpm & ubuntu 16.04) but when I try visiting my URL without port I get a 404, and when I visit apiname.laravelsite.com I get a 403..

My NGINX config from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/dorsia;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
            #
            # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
            # Don't use them in a production server!
            #
            # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

            root /var/www/dorsia;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name _;

            location / {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            #
            #location ~ \.php$ {
            #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #
            #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            #       fastcgi_pass 45.55.184.33:8125;
            #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            #}

            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            #location ~ /\.ht {
            #       deny all;
            #}
    }


    # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    #
    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
    #
    #server {
    #       listen 80;
    #       listen [::]:80;
    #
    #       server_name example.com;
    #
    #       root /var/www/example.com;
    #       index index.html;
    #
                #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                #}

                # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
                # concurs with nginx's one
                #
                #location ~ /\.ht {
                #       deny all;
                #}
        }


        # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
        #
        # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
        # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
        #
        #server {
        #       listen 80;
        #       listen [::]:80;
        #
        #       server_name example.com;
        #
        #       root /var/www/example.com;
        #       index index.html;
        #
        #       location / {
        #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #       }
        #}
```

Comment: you can consider using homestead. it make the work flow alot easier.

Comment: Nice, considering it, except, I already build my API, have node, php 7, composer etc already installed. Isn't using homestead then too much of a hassle? @SSuhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a config like below will work.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name _;

  charset utf-8;
  root "/var/www/dorsia/public";

  access_log /var/log/nginx/dorsia-acc.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/dorsia-err.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /\.ht        { deny all; }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** also make sure that the right user/group is set up on `fpm`'s config, so it can access and run the php files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this let you know the results. Btw, this user is root, is that a problem?

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn It will sure have access to the files than. But consider changing it to a specific user for the app when going to production.

Comment: Btw, this is not for any web routes, my laravel is rest api only and my front end is probably a client on another domain, so I shouldn't point to my public folder right? @balintant

Comment: not working with your config, still cant access without my port (and returns me a 403 and 404) :(

Comment: Pointing to a public folder is considered the safest solution. I will look into it at home. 

Comment: Okay will do that for now, keep me updated! @balintant

Comment: I fixed it with you config, the path to my php7.0-fpm.sock was wrong, thanks :). However, now pointing to my public folder, how do I really serve my API so that I can make requests? @balintant

Comment: I had to put ipv6only=on before listening to [::]:80, nginx was listening to port 80 twice. It's all working now without using my port, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn glad you have solved that issue. Enjoy your development and serving!

Comment: You might also want to set up the body size and other options btw.

Comment: Will look into that, just configured SSL, so I'm starting developing now :) @balintant